# QGIS Openlayers tool not showing tiles, but showing question mark

Tags: qgis, python, tiles, qgis-openlayers-plugin

We have a proxy server which I've added to QGIS, but when I load openlayers, I get a grid with lots of questions marks, yet the watermark is supplied; any ideas?  Fiddler doesn't show anything out of the ordinary.

[image]

Comment: Try Stamen and Google Tiles first - related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73736/openlayers-from-behind-a-proxy

Comment: I've tried both; not one layer will open, but I get the disclaimer.  It's really odd. I have set up the proxy server correctly and I am getting a grid, but no images.  May try this at home later.