# Python error while trying to use openlayers_plugin as basemap

Tags: qgis

While trying to use openlayerPlugin in QGIS as base map. I am getting below error

```
warning:C:/Users/*User_Id*/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py:174: DeprecationWarning: QgsMapLayer.setLayerName() is deprecated
          layer.setLayerName(layerType.displayName)

    traceback:  File "C:/Users/*User_Id*/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
        self._addLayerCallback(self)
```

..I have tried running it with/without proxy unchecked and getting same error both time.

Note: I dont have admin rights to the workspace system.

Comment: That's not an error, that's a warning.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @AManKaushik! Your OpenLayers plugin might be outdated which would make it incompatible with the QGIS version you are using. You may have to use the [latest version of the plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/) or better yet, use the **QuickMapServices** plugin :)

Comment: hi @kthy, i understand it. But since its my first time using GIS and i am waiting for 2 hrs for it to appear as basemap. I thought it must be the issue,

Comment: @Joseph, thanks... I have used latest version only.but its showing these warning. 
Moreover, i am new to python as a language so couldn't understand much. 

Also, should i keep Proxy on or off?

Comment: Depends if you're behind a firewall or proxy server. Perhaps the following posts might help: [OpenLayers plugin for QGIS problem with maps loading](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73925/openlayers-plugin-for-qgis-problem-with-maps-loading); and [OpenLayers from behind a proxy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73736/openlayers-from-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: sorry for the simple question like this.. but can this be the reason for the unsuccessful loading of basemap
*2017-09-07T18:17:59 1 Failed to load C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/plugins/globeplugin.dll (Reason: Cannot load library C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/plugins/globeplugin.dll: The specified module could not be found.)*